# Why const_cast is not modifying the value in caller function?

Tags: c++, linux, constants

For below snippet,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void fun(const int *p)
{
    int *q = const_cast<int *>(p);
    *q = *q * 10;
    cout<<"q: "<<q<<"\t Value: "<<*q<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    const int a = 10;
    const int *z = &a;
    fun(z);
    cout<<"z: "<<z<<"\t"<<"Address of a: "<<&a<<endl;
    cout<<"value at z: "<<*z<<"\t\t value in a: "<<a<<endl;
}
```

the output produced is

```
q: 0x7fff65910fcc    Value: 100
z: 0x7fff65910fcc   Address of a: 0x7fff65910fcc
value at z: 100      value in a: 10
```

Why the value of a is not modified even though i tried to modify it in fun()?

How come the address of a and the pointer z are same but the values are different?

Is it some kind of undefined behavior with const_cast ?

Comment: Please note that the compiler might want to use the information you give him about constness to perform some optimization... (This is the second reason for taking care about constness; the first being "nice code" which tells the programmer that it doesn't touch your data)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it some kind of undefined behavior with const_cast ?

**Yes**, your program contains undefined behavior.

This means that you cannot have any expectation on its output. The reason is given by paragraph 7.1.6.1/4 of the C++11 Standard:

> Except that any class member declared `mutable` (7.1.1) can be modified, any attempt to modify a `const`
>   object during its lifetime (3.8) results in undefined behavior

Paragraph 5.2.11/7 on `const_cast` contains a further warning:

> [ *Note*: Depending on the type of the object, a write operation through the pointer, lvalue or pointer
>   to data member resulting from a `const_cast` that casts away a `const`-qualifier may produce undefined
>   behavior (7.1.6.1). —*end note* ]

Comment: Basically you can use `const_cast` to cast away `const` on something that is not actually `const` only.  The compiler is free to store `const` objects in ROM or do optimizations assuming they are never changed (like change that print statement to print a constant compile time value, or whatever else it feels like)